# How to create same pdf file multiple time using tcpdf in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I'm using tcpdf library for pdf creation. I want to download same pdf multiple time(user will enter how many pdfs he want). I made a for loop which call pdf function according to the user entered value. The problem is code stop after creating first pdf. Following is my pdf function which I call multiple time. Also it take about 10-15 seconds to create pdf. Thanks!

```
    public function generatePdf($eventId) {
    $eventDetails = $this->events_model->getAttachment($eventId);
    $image = $eventDetails[0]->image_source;
    $startTime = $eventDetails[0]->startTime;
    $regTime = $eventDetails[0]->regTime;
    $locationName = $eventDetails[0]->location_name;
    $location = $eventDetails[0]->location;
    $date = strtotime($startTime);
    $date1 = strtotime($regTime);
    $dat = date('m/d/y', $date);
    $tme = date('H:m', $date);
    $regTme = date('m/d/ H:m', $date1);



    $this->load->library('Pdf');
    $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

    $pdf->SetTitle('Event Ticket');
    $pdf->SetTopMargin(0);
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(true);
    $pdf->setFooterMargin(0);
    $pdf->setLeftMargin(0);
    $pdf->setRightMargin(0);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('MPM');
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetFontSize('10');
    $pdf->SetFont('', 'B');
    $y = $pdf->getY();

    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 1, 2, 1);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(215, 235, 255);
    $event_pic = './eventDocs/' . $image;
    $logo_html = '<img width="196px;" height="700px;"  src="' . base_url() . $event_pic . '" />';

    $event_fixed_pic = './eventDocs/Untitled-2.png';
    $event_fixed_pic_html = '<img height="200px;"  src="' . base_url() . $event_fixed_pic . '" />';

    $event_bottom_pic = './eventDocs/Untitled-4447.png';
    $event_bottom_pic_html = '<img width="595px;" height="146px;"  src="' . base_url() . $event_bottom_pic . '" />';

    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(80, 280, '', $y, $logo_html, 0, 0, 0, false, '', true);

    $pdf->setCellPaddings(60, 1, 2, 1);
    $pdf->SetFont('', 'B', 14);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(195, 195, 176);
    $pdf->MultiCell(130, 5, $startTime, 0, false, 0, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(25);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(75, 0, 2, 1);
    $pdf->SetFont('', 'B', 15);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
    $pdf->MultiCell(140, 5, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_top_heading1")), 0, false, 0, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(6);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(75, 0, 2, 1);
    $pdf->MultiCell(170, 5, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_top_heading2")), 0, false, 0, 0, '', '', true);

    $linestyle = array('width' => 1.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => '', 'phase' => 0, 'color' => array(195, 195, 176));
    $pdf->Line(75, 40, 149, 40, $linestyle);
    $pdf->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 0.3, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0)));

    $pdf->Ln(18);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(75, 0, 2, 1);
    $pdf->SetFont('', 'B', 11);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
    $pdf->MultiCell(150, 5, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_heading1")), 0, false, 0, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(8);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(75, 0, 2, 1);
    $pdf->MultiCell(200, 5, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_heading2")), 0, false, 0, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(38);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(5, 0, 2, 1);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(75);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(199, 195, 176);
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(60, 43, 0, 95, $locationName . '<br>' . $location, 0, 0, 1, false, '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(140);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(140, 95);
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell('', 30, '', $y, $event_fixed_pic_html, 0, 0, 0, false, '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(60);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 0, 2, 1);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(75);
    $pdf->MultiCell(100, 5, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_heading3")), 0, false, 0, 0, '', '', true);

    $linestyle = array('width' => 1.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => '', 'phase' => 0, 'color' => array(195, 195, 176));
    $pdf->Line(75, 163, 146, 163, $linestyle);
    $pdf->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 0.3, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0)));

    $pdf->Ln(11);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 0, 2, 1);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(75);
    $pdf->SetFont('', '', 10);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
    $pdf->MultiCell(120, 5, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_heading3_para1")), 0, false, 0, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(35);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 0, 2, 1);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(75);
    $pdf->MultiCell(120, 5, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_heading3_para2")), 0, false, 0, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 0, 2, 1);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(75);
    $pdf->MultiCell(120, 5, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_heading3_para3")), 0, false, 0, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 0, 2, 1);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(75);
    $pdf->MultiCell(100, 5, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_heading3_para4")), 0, false, 0, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(0, 240);
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(500, 52, '', $y, $event_bottom_pic_html, 0, 0, 1, false, '', true);

    $pdf->SetFont('', '', 12);
    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 15, 2, 1);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(10);
    $pdf->MultiCell(50, 30, $locationName . '    ' . $location, 0, false, 1, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 10, 2, 1);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(70);
    $pdf->MultiCell(50, 10, $dat, 0, false, 1, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 13, 2, 1);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(70);
    $pdf->MultiCell(50, 10, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_footer_para3")) . $regTme . $this->lang->line("event_pdf_footer_time"), 0, false, 1, 0, '', '', true);

    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 18, 2, 1);
    $pdf->setCellMargins(70);
    $pdf->MultiCell(50, 10, utf8_to_german($this->lang->line("event_pdf_footer_para4")) . $tme . $this->lang->line("event_pdf_footer_time"), 0, false, 1, 0, '', '', true);

    ob_end_clean();
    $pdf->Output('pdfexample.pdf', 'D');
   $pdf->Output('pdfexample1.pdf', 'D');
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't know php but it must be easier to create the pdf once and download it multiple times. Also, why would someone want the same file multiple times? If the do, can't they copy it locally?

Comment: @Holloway you are right, no one want to download same file multiple times but my client want this...actually pdf is not created on server, it just show a popup from which user can select download option. I want that popup appears 5 times if user enter 5, but right now it just show one popup and also code after that stop executing.

Comment: @UmairMalik, My suggestion is create one file and make n copies of the same file and compress it as ZIP, This process will be very fast when compare to creating PDF files again and again.  And down load ZIP file to client.

Comment: I suggest you to call the function once, and inside the function just looping to create pdf file with multipage that's needed

Comment: I also want same functionality have you got any solution for it?

Comment: @Freedom i went with the solution given by jitendra to create one file and the create copied of it and zip it. Otherwise there is no solution to do this as far as I searched on google.